# Logic/reasoning confusion in UGC book re network/relational logical/physical keys & schema/metatdata/dictionary

Tags: database, relational-database, metadata, database-schema, data-dictionary

I was just going through the questions of UGC-NET(GS) & GATE(CS/IT), in which I had some difficulties.

There are some questions whose answers are different than my answers.
Can you help me find the solution and tell me whether I am wrong or the answers given are wrong? What is the reasoning behind their answers and, if different, the correct answers?

> Q 1: Choose the correct statement.
>   (a) Network models are complicated by physical key, but the relational model is faster because it uses logical keys.
>   (b) Network models are complicated by logical key, but the relational model is faster because it uses physical keys.
>   (c) Network models are complicated by physical key, but the relational model is slower because it uses logical keys.
>   (d) Network models are complicated by logical key, but the relational model is slower because it uses physical keys.
>
> Q 2: The schema of a relation is an example of
>   a. Data Dictionary
>   b. Metadata
>   c. Entity
>   d. Relationship

According to me answer of Q 1 is a but it is given b(according to book).
According to me answer of Q 2 is a but it is given b(according to book).

These are basic questions but a little bit confusing and it is important to know the logic behind them.

Comment: 1. I guess you mean UGC-NET(CS)? 2. Where did you get these questions & answers? What have you found googling for relevant database textbook pdf text re these topics? 3. What is your reasoning? What are your references?

Comment: I see that you have never "accepted" an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can do that to show you were helped. Imaginary unicorn interweb reputation points are earned. You can also edit your questions to be clearer and/or more researched.

Answer (score 1):

Googling the text of Q1 a we find [Multiplechoice Questions in Computer Science](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5tatBaRplIgC&printsec=frontcover) has these choices in a different order as [question 35 on page 247](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5tatBaRplIgC&pg=PA247&focus=viewport) and gives answer [**physical-faster-logical** on page 249](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5tatBaRplIgC&pg=PA249&focus=viewport) as its a. This is also **your choice a**. (For my guess at a rationale for b, see below.)

That's what we would expect from a network model's logical keys typically also being physical keys and the relational model's logical keys having no fixed association with physical keys. (Nevertheless it's not correct to say the relational model is faster, see below.)

PS The *correct* distinction between the models is that network model logical keys are *an unnecessary data structure in addition to tables* and that typically it has *meaningful logical order* to keys, rows and/or columns. (The point of using a network model is to have logical keys that are physical keys, but that's irrelevant when comparing the *models*, see below.)

---

**Q1 (e) None of the above.** That is a terrible question for multiple reasons. Eg: "uses logical keys (in the model)" can mean "can optimize physical keys (in execution)" which could be phrased as "uses physical keys (in execution)". Eg: Both models are "logical" until you hypothesize a physical model. So the network model is "complicated by logical keys". But the point of the network model is that its logical keys *are* physical keys for the *actual* physical model. So it is "complicated by physical keys".

Find exactly what a reference textbook means by the various terms. Apparently unfortunately your exams can depend pedantically on artifacts of how a topic happens to be phrased in the reference material and how the particular wording in the exams is interpreted.

Here's a *guess* at a justification for (b): The network model is "complicated by logical keys (in the model)". A relational DBMS can typically optimize query execution "logically" by rewriting based on relational algebra equivalences and "physically" via statistics and indexes. A network DBMS query execution can't be "logically" optimized and a query is either fast because the logical=physical keys were chosen to make it fast or is slow because the logical=physical keys were chosen to make *other* queries fast. So the relational execution/implementation will not be impeded by inappropriate "physical key use" and will be both logically & physically optimized in its "physical key use". (Nevertheless the specialization/hardwiring of non-relational keys/queries *does* make them faster *in some cases*.)

**Q2 (b).** A definition of "data dictionary" typically doesn't include constraints. A definition of "schema" can include constraints. A definition of "metadata" typically does include constraints. A data dictionary is a database schema (minus constraints if so defined). A database schema is all the metadata (minus constraints if so defined). But a *table* schema is just *some* of "the" metadata, ie it "is an example of metadata". (Nevertheless, more difficulties with unclear language.)